# Indenting plain text in a .text.haml file in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

In my rails 3.1 app I am working on a text email backup and want it to show up in the email client as text separated into new lines like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Consectetur adipisicing elit
Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
Ut labore et d  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Consectetur adipisicing elit Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt Ut labore et dolore magna aliquaolore magna aliqua
```

In my .text.haml file I have tried to use this:

```
:plain
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  Consectetur adipisicing elit
  Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
```

However, when I check it in gmail it appears condensed into one paragraph like this:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Consectetur adipisicing elit Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua

What can I do to get this to work?  When I copy and paste this code into a view file, and view source, it appears as text as I want it in the view source, but gets condensed into one paragraph in the browser.  Does this perhaps indicate that gmail is taking the text and formatting it that way and I don't actually have a problem?

Comment: Have you tried `:escaped` or `:preserve`? See also http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_preservation

Comment: What content-type are you sending the mail as? If it’s `text/html` then all your whitespace will be condensed into a single space when displayed, and you’ll see it condensed into one line like this.

Comment: It's a .text.haml but how do I know what content-type I'm sending as?

Comment: @John to be honest I don’t really know – a quick look at the docs suggests that it should see `text.haml` and send it as text. You should be able to look at the original mail in Gmail and check what the header is there – look for the “Show original” option. Having said that though, using Haml to send plain text seems to miss the point. Haml maps the indentation of the source to the hierarchical nature of HTML; using it to create plain text doesn’t make much sense. I’d advise just using ERB, even if you can get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a setup to test this, but I believe you want either `:escaped` or `:preserve` (probably the latter).

If those don't work, see http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#filters for others (including info on how to create your own).

Comment: Neither :escaped or :preserve produce the desired effect in gmail.  Also tried :erb but not sure if I'm getting the correct erb syntax.

Comment: Can you view the raw email?  In GMail, choose "show original" like this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/13262/44019/4niv1y3phdsvgo9/Screen%20Shot%202012-09-06%20at%204.28.42%20PM.png In particular, find out the content type of the email and of the different mime parts.

Comment: You want to make sure the plain text part is `Content-Type: text/plain;`